# Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1 Received http2 header with status: 404

Tags: c#, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We are trying to call the Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1 predict API using the .Net client and keep getting the following error:   Received http2 header with status: 404

We setup credentials using the API key and environment variable:  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Here is the code to call the vertex AI predict API:

```
const string projectId = "xxxxxx";
const string location = "us-central1"; 
const string endpointId = "xxxxxx";  

PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.Create();

var structVal = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value.ForStruct(new Struct
{
    Fields =
    {
    ["mimeType"] = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value.ForString("text/plain"),
    // Sample contents is a string constant defined in a separate file
    ["content"] = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value.ForString(Consts.SampleContents)
    }
});

PredictRequest req = new PredictRequest()
{
    EndpointAsEndpointName = EndpointName.FromProjectLocationEndpoint(projectId, location, endpointId),
    Instances = { structVal }
};

PredictResponse response = client.Predict(req);
```

The full error returned:

Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Received http2 header with status: 404", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1644947338.412000000","description":"Received http2 :status header with non-200 OK status","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\http\client\http_client_filter.cc","file_line":134,"grpc_message":"Received http2 header with status: 404","grpc_status":12,"value":"404"}")

I validate the same call using CURL and was able to successfully make the call.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/ui/projects/XXXXXX/locations/us-central1/endpoints/XXXXXX:predict -d @payload.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think, we had same problem
and I was resolve that

PredictionServiceClient -> Need EndPoint of PredictionServiceClient Set,

```
PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.Create();
```

change please

```
PredictionServiceClientBuilder ClientBuilder = new PredictionServiceClientBuilder();
ClientBuilder .Endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com";

PredictionServiceClient client = ClientBuilder.Build();
```

thanks